# IntraWeb service silent install

Tags: intraweb

Can I install Intraweb service in "silent mode"?

```
service.exe /install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this answer may be a little bit late.

/Silent will not work, since in the event of an error a dialogbox will be created.

You have to compile your application with the:

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

Answer (score 1):

Just add `/silent` as parameter